# Navigation Drawer stops working after implementing MaterialSearchView

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, material-design, searchview

My main activity consists of a navigation drawer and switching between fragments was working fine. Now i tried to implement Material Searchview using [this](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) library which requires the toolbar to be set last inside the xml file. So now my serachview is working fine but onNavigationItemSelected stops working and i cant switch between fragments. If inside the xml i write navigation drawer below the toolbar navigation starts working again but searchview stops working. Please help me.

activity_home.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    />

                <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

HomeActivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        exploreFragment();
        searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        searchView.setVoiceSearch(false);
        searchView.setCursorDrawable(R.drawable.custom_cursor);
        searchView.setEllipsize(true);
//        searchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,query,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            exploreFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            newFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    public void exploreFragment(){
        fragment = new ExploreFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//        bundle.putString("loginToken",loginToken);
//        bundle.putString("userId", userId);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
    public void newFragment(){
        fragment = new NewFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//        bundle.putString("loginToken",loginToken);
//        bundle.putString("userId", userId);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please put your Log cat.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add actionviewclass

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView" />
```